# Is it possible to manually transfer pod files instead of running `pod install`?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I had issues Installing Firebase pods to my project on my laptop so I decided to use my friend's Macbook to Install it to my Xcode swift project and it worked. Will I be able to call the pod libraries that  I have added to my project by copy pasting the folder to my laptop even though I used my friends laptop to add the pod files. I have installed cocoapods already it just it had issues when I used the command "pod install".

Thanks for your time. I am totally new at this Xcode stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get away with that depending on whether or not the files for each pod are still included in your project when you transfer it, but generally, the practice when transferring code (an Xcode project) to another computer is to run `pod install`. Running `pod install` shouldn't cause any problems and it would be a better idea to fix the `pod install` problems in order to streamline efficiency for future projects than to manually transfer files from one computer to another (even if it works)